# sampling rate in .wav file

Tags: sample-rate, wav

Hi everyone!
I'm a newbie in sound generating and currently I'm coding assembly for playing a .wav file. What I have learned by all my searching is that in the structure of a .wav file there is some number "sample rate". I wanted to know if my understanding of this sample rate is correct.

Let's assume that the sampling rate, noted in the subchunk of a .wav file is 8000hz. Does it mean that when playing the sound, 8000 of those samples per second should be played? so that this way I can calculate how much time a note (or a sample) shall hold on.

Is what I have assumed correct?

thanks in advance

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_rate

Answer (score 8):

Yes.            .